# Why my C++ program can't get me the value which I have assigned before instead of random double?

Tags: c++, string, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have been working on a project which handles Matrices and make operations with it. I'm doing it to learn memory management and understand object-oriented programming. So, first, I don't want to use a matrix library.

In my class, I made a constructor for Matrix class which has three parameters: `int row_number, int column_number, string inside_expression`. inside_expression is a way to create matrix and assign values in it. Using template of inside_expression is looks like MatLab but without handling spaces:

Ex. `maths::Matrix matrix1(3, 3, "1,5.7,6;23,4,0;5,5,2;");`

It doesn't need to be square matrix by the way. maths is the name of namespace.

So, for now, everything works perfectly. Program makes a poly-dimensional array with doubles and after it did, it gave the console a looking of matrix for debugging purposes. I was testing the code for every possible givens and I saw a mistaken output. If last element of last column and last row on a matrix is zero, it assigns `_matrix[last_row][last_col] = 0` but after assignment, if I want to print the value it gives me a random double.

Why it makes that? I'll copy my constructor function down here. Thank you for all. :) Have a nice day.

```cpp
Matrix::Matrix(int _row, int _column, std::string _inside) {
        //std::cout << _inside << "\n";
        row = _row - 1;
        col = _column - 1;

        // Matrix Creation with Arrays
        _matrix = new double*[row];
        for (int index = 0; index <= row; index++) {
            _matrix[index] = new double[col];
        }

        /* Template for creating matrix: "1,5.4,6,7;8.7,9,7,3;15,4,7,2;"
         Because of that we need to find their positions on string
         and store them as two dimensional array.
         [first;    ,   sec;   ,    third;]
         [1,          [8.7,          [15,
        5.4,             9,            4,
          6,             7,            7,
          7]             3]            2]
        */

        int row_cursor = 0; // For row value.

        while (true) {
            int pos = _inside.find(";");
            //std::cout << "\tpos: " << pos << "\n";

            // If there's no ; character, it'll break the while loop.
            if (pos == std::string::npos) {
                if (row_cursor == 0) {std::cerr << "Given matrix is invalid type!";}
                break;
            }

            // Finding commas and inserting numbers to matrix.
            for (int index = 0; index <= col; index++) {
                int item_pos = _inside.substr(0, pos).find(",");
                //std::cout << "\t\titem_pos: " << item_pos << "\n";

                // If can't find comma (when x;y,z,f; situation happens)
                if (item_pos == -1 || item_pos >= pos) {
                    int _OLD_POS = pos;
                    pos = _inside.find(";");
                    //std::cout << "\t\tnew pos: " << pos << "\n";
                    _matrix[row_cursor][index] = std::stod(_inside.substr(0, pos));
                    //std::cout << "\t\tmsubstr val: " << _inside.substr(0, pos) << "\t";
                    //std::cout << "matix value: " << _matrix[row_cursor][index] << "\n";
                    _inside.erase(0, pos + 1);
                    //std::cout << "\t\terased _inside: " << _inside << "\n";
                    pos = _OLD_POS - _inside.substr(0, pos).length();
                    //std::cout << "\t-> pos: " << pos << "\n";

                } else {
                    _matrix[row_cursor][index] = std::stod(_inside.substr(0, item_pos));
                    //std::cout << "\t\tmsubstr val: " << _inside.substr(0, item_pos) << "\t";
                    _inside.erase(0, item_pos + 1);
                    //std::cout << "\t\terased _inside: " << _inside << "\n";
                    pos = pos - _inside.substr(0, item_pos).length();
                    //std::cout << "\t-> pos: " << pos << "\n";
                }
            }

            row_cursor++;
        }

        // To see matrix:
        for (int index = 0; index <= row; index++) {
            for (int jindex = 0; jindex <= col; jindex++) {
                std::cout << _matrix[index][jindex] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
```

> Note about code: I commentted the console prints to not disturb you.

Comment: `index <= row` is a bug that causes it to loop 1 time too many causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @drescherjm And there are more conditions like that, all buggy from a brief look.

Comment: your fiddling around with  `-1` is confusing. Everything uses 0-based indices in C++, better do the same, doing something differnt is recipe for desaster.

Comment: First fix `row = _row - 1;` and `col = _column - 1;` to `row = _row;` and `column = _column;` then change all `index <= row` to `index < row` and `index <= col` to `index < col`. There may be other bugs in addition to these.

Comment: @drescherjm What would it change? For giving row number 3, my code loops 0,1,2 because I delete 1. With correction which you suggested, giving row number 3, code loops 0,1,2. I'll change it but I can't understand what will change for program?

Comment: If _row is 3 you allocate space for 2 rows. And currently you loop 0,1 and 2 but again you allocated only 2 rows so valid indices of 0 and 1. Using the third row is out of bounds.

Comment: @drescherjm Oh I see, it worked, thank you so much! I'll revision my code. Any other suggestion about the mess I did above? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last valid index into an array with `row` elements is `row-1`. Here you create an array with `row` elements and the last iteration of the loop tries to access `_matrix[row]` but that is not part of the array.

```
_matrix = new double*[row];
for (int index = 0; index <= row; index++) {
    _matrix[index] = new double[col];
}
```

Accessing an array out-of-bounds invokes undefined behavior. Executing your code, anything or nothing can happen.

Common convention is to use 0-based indexing and half open intervals, ie your loop should be

```
for (size_t index = 0; index < row; ++index)
                          // ^----------------- !!!
```

PS: Using 0-based or 1-based indexing each has pros and cons. The important thing about a convention is not that it has no alternatives that are as valid, but that you apply it consistently. Don't mix 0 and 1-based indexing. It will be a mess.

Comment: Oh, I understood it now. So there are two solutions. One of them is changing the _matrix's element size to "row + 1": `_matrix = new double*[row+1];`. Second, I should change my code for 0-base indexed algorithm. I had tried after you people told me, first solution (row+1), it works. Thank you again. I want to optimize my code for 0 indexed, i think.

Comment: @GKO no, there is only one solution: Change your code to use 0-based indexing ;) sorry if that wasnt clear enough

Comment: You were clear enough, thank you! If I change my code to 0-indexed, the user who's going to use library, of course only me, need to specify row and column one less, am I right? I just want to make it like MatLab.

Comment: @GKO in your example `matrix1(3, 3,...` should create a matrix with 3x3 elements, that would be `double matrix[3][3];` and a loop would be `for (int i=0; i<3;++i)...` You never need to add or subtract `1`